# Django: messages.error doesn't work with redirect('/')

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, django-messages

I'm so confused in templates main page I have:

```
{% for message in messages %}                                     
 {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}           
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
 {% endif %}                                                      
{% endfor %}
```

but the message is not printed. in views.py I have

```
def my_form(request):

 if not str(request.POST['name']):                               
     messages.error(request,'error message.')                          
     return redirect('/')
```

and in myapp urls.py

```
path('', views.index, name='index'),                                   
re_path(r'^MyForm/$', views.my_form, name='my_form')
```

and in the general urls.py

```
re_path(r'^', include('myapp.urls'), name='home')
```

what could be the issue, the log file shows nothing

Comment: Can you please confirm you have `django.contrib.messages` in `INSTALLED_APPs`, `MIDDLEWARE` contains `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` and `django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware`. Also, the `context_processors` option of the DjangoTemplates backend defined in your `TEMPLATES` setting contains `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages`.